# Why does Google's Lighthouse bot (when run from Google's servers) not use gzip compression for loading from my site?

Tags: bots, lighthouse

I checked this behavior of Google's Lighthouse bot and it seems consistent across several sites I can check. I will use one page as example:

https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16

When I load this webpage on Chrome, the main page HTML loads as gzipped.

- In desktop, when I look up the performance entry using `window.performance.getEntriesByName` I see a `transferSize` of 26866 and a `decodedBodySize` of 145861.
- The corresponding numbers in mobile are `transferSize` of 24191 and `decodedBodySize` of 133739.

When I run Lighthouse from within Chrome Dev Tools, I similarly see a `transferSize` of 26866 and a `decodedBodySize` of 145861 for desktop , and `transferSize` of 24191 and `decodedBodySize` of 133739 for mobile emulation.

However, when I visit https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgroupprops.subwiki.org%2Fwiki%2FGroups_of_order_16 to trigger a Lighthouse score calculation for the page, the Google bot that visits the page does not request them gzipped. In fact the `transferSize` for mobile emulation is 134337, a little higher than the `decodedBodySize` due to headers. (To capture this information I logged the data using JavaScript running on the page and sent it back to a server).

I confirmed across a diverse range of sites with different setups that Lighthouse bot loads of pages made through the PageSpeed Insights UI (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), or the corresponding API, do not use gzip compression even when it's enabled on the server and used by all modern clients.

Ideas?